# how to display a number without decimal using sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my SQL Statement:

```
SELECT
distance, distance / 12 AS Feet, distance mod 12 as Inches
FROM products
```

It assign the value of 28.77083 to Feet.

How do I assign just the value 28 to Feet.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: how about `floor()`, [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_floor)

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_floor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT distance, floor(distance / 12) AS Feet, distance mod 12 as Inches
from
products
```

The mysql [Floor function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_floor)

> Returns the largest integer value not greater than X.

Comment: Shouldn't the first `distance` be outside the `floor()`? ^^

Comment: sorry @FirstOne, half asleep

Comment: perhaps I should say, whatever column is the problem, floor it

Comment: Thank you. The floor(distance / 12) as Feet worked just like I wanted it to.

Comment: glad to hear it @gehrenfeld, please mark question Answered with the Green check mark ([Here is how](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147532)). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple function to omit out decimals

> Select Str(34523.1245, 12, 3);

where 12 is the total number of characters to display, 3 is the decimal places

OR

Try This

> SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(5,0),Distance);

OR

You can define precision in SQL Server by Numeric

> NUMERIC(10,2);

which means that the column will have total of 10 digits and upto decimal precision of 2 digits